# Transferring ownership to a manager

Tags: c++, memory, c++11, memory-management, ownership

I am trying to write a managerial class for entities in a component based system. I am unsure of how to proceed with adding entities into this class. I have though of a few ways of doing this, however I am not sure what the correct method is.

The first method would be to *move* the object into the manager.

```
void addEntity(Entity && in){
  entities.emplace(std::move(in));
}
```

However, then I need to deal with move constructors, which shouldn't be too hard.

Another way of doing it is passing in a pointer or `std::unique_ptr`. This way, I don't need to worry about ownership as much as it would invalidate the pointer that is passed in.

```
void addEntity(std::unique_ptr<Entity> in){
  entities.emplace(in);
}
```

However, I am unsure of which method, if either, is better.

Comment: What does "move the object into the manager" really mean?  Why not simply give the manager the address of the object and leave it in place?

Comment: Hard to say for sure without more context, but the first one seems fine to me. One of the primary reasons to consider the second one would be if you were dealing with polymorphic `Entity` types.

Comment: @wallyk I want the manager to have ownership of the entity. I would probably read from a file these entities, and add them sequentially to the manager so that they get destroyed when they need to, but otherwise exist within it.

Comment: @Praetorian Enttiy will not be a polymorphic type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first method only works if you call it with rvalues from client code. This is a big limitation so you would have to provide another overload for an lvalue reference. You can actually do both at the same time if you use a "universal reference" with perfect forwarding to `emplace`. The downside is that it uses templates so the `Entity` type disappears from the signature:

```
template <typename T>
void addEntity(T&& in){
  entities.emplace(std::forward<T>(in));
}
```

The `unique_ptr` way is a bit more verbose for the client because they have to create the `unique_ptr` themselves.

```
Entity entity(...);
manager.addEntity(std::make_unique<Entity>(entity)); // copy ctor
// or
manager.addEntity(std::make_unique<Entity>(std::move(entity))); // move ctor to heap
```

It comes down to the decision about whose responsibility it should be to create the unique object. Do you want the Manager class to take ownership of some already existing unique object that the client prepares for you, or would you rather have a more flexible Manager class that will do the move/copy itself depending on the provided argument.

I'd go with the perfect forwarding or the two-overloads solution because it results in a cleaner interface and nicer client code.